# What are the rules for wearing Rudraksha bead?

Tags: shiva, rudraksha

I want to wear the Rudraksha bead but have some queries related to the rules. What are the exact rules?

Comment: Its not right to ask here..Because i don't think u can wear it just because u want to wear it..Someone must have prescribed the Rudraksha be it ur Guru or an Acharya or a Sadhu(Sannyasi) or a priest or an astrologer....That person will tell what the rules are which u need to follow after wearing it..BTW, there are indeed some rules..

Comment: @Rickross as per this link `http://www.rudraksham.com/choosing-rudraksha` it says anyone can wear it. Gems are suppose to be used by astrologer calculation. I dont find anything against Rudraksh

Comment: @Mongrel..No AFaIK its not safe to wear even rudrakshas without guidance..There are a lot of Rudraksha types..How will u be sure which one is the best for u?Rudrakshas are usually prescribed based on one's nakshtras..For example for Sun's nakshtras one-mukhi for moon's nakshtras two-mukhi and so on..I think u better consult some experienced astrologer before wearing one..[Here](http://www.astrojyoti.com/rudrakshapage.htm) is a page u mite find useful.Read all the subsequent pages too..

Comment: @Rickross Anyone can wear five faced Rudraksha.

Comment: ..Usually the 5 mukhi ones are best suited for natives of jupiter's nakshtras to wear..In any case if it was the case of me wearing one i'll consult an astrologer before wearing it..my advice is that u should also do the same..

Comment: @Rickross got your point, but who will be the best person. any astrologer or some pundit.

Comment: I don't know if i can recommend someone here but still Pandit S.P.Tata from Astrojyoti.com is one u can consult & rely upon..I already linked a page from his website in an earlier comment..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Rules for wearing Rudraksha are discussed in **Vidyes’vara Samhita ,Chapter 25 (The Glory of the Rudraksha) in Shiva Maha-Purana.**

These are some of the Rules -:

> शिरसीशानमन्त्रेण कर्णे तत्पुरुषेण च | 
>     अघोरेण गले धार्यं तेनैव ह्य्रुदयेsपि च ||40||
>
> One should wear Rudraksha reciting the **Isana-mantra** ,with
>   **Tatpurusha in ears** and with **Aghora mantra** , over the heart.Rudrakasha thus be worn.
>
> ---
>
> मद्यं मासं तु लशुनं पलाण्डु शिग्रुमेव च | 
>  
>     श्लेष्मान्तकं  विड वराहं भक्षणे वर्जयेत्ततः ||43||
>
> A person wearing Rudraksha beads ,**shall not eat meat** ,garlic
>   ,onion ,red garlic potherb glutinous fruits ,pig of rubbish and
>   **wine.**
>
> ---
>
> वलक्षं रुद्राक्षं द्विजतनुभिरेवेह् विहितं 
>  
>     सुरक्तं क्षत्राणान प्रमिदितमुमे पितमसकृतं
>  
>     ततो वैश्येर्धार्यं प्रतिदिवसमावश्यकमहो 
>     तथा कृष्णं शुद्रै: श्रुतिगदितमार्गोsयमगजे || 44 || 
>     O Parvati
>   ,the **White  Rudrakasha  should be worn by the Brahmanas , the Red by
>   Kshatriyas ,yellow by the vaishyas ,while the black should be used by
>   the Sudras**.This has been propounded by the Vedas.
>
> ---
>
> **उपवीते** त्रयं धार्यं शिवभक्तिरतैर्नरै:| 
>       शेषानृर्वरितान्पच्त्र सम्मितान धारयेत्कटो: ||30||
>
> A Devotee of Shiva Should wear **three beads in the yajnopavita and
>   five in waist.**
>
> ---
>
> धात्रीफलप्रमाणं यत् श्रेष्ठमेतदुदाहॄतम् ।
>    बदरीफलमात्रं तु मध्यमं संप्रकीर्तितं ॥14॥
>
> Rudraksha of size of Embolic Myrobaln is considered to be the best.The
>   one is size of Jujube fruit is considered to be the middle one.

Comment: How do we wear rudraksha in upavita? also I think it should be उपवीते. Also add which rudraksha represents what.

Comment: The sanskrit word "Upavite" is for "Yajnopavita" as we can see fron the shloka ,We can wear 3 beads in Yajnopabita , but it's not mentioned in Shiva-Purana "How".

Answer (score 10):

Adding one important rule which the selected answer has not mentioned. Apart from energizing the Rudraksha beads with Panchakshara and Trayambaka Shiva mantras, each of the 14 types of Rudrakshas has to be worn by the devotee **only after chanting a particular mantra that is associated with that particular type of Rudraksha .**

By not doing so one accrues sins. The 14 mantras can be found in both Padma and Skanda Puranas with some variations.

> NischidrAscha SupakkAscha RudrakshadhArane SmritAha |
>  PanchAmritam
>   Panchagavyam SnAnakAle Prajojayeth |
>  RudrAkshasya PratishthAyAm
>   Mantram PanchAksharam TathA |
>  TryambakAdimantrancha TathA Tatra
>   Prajojayeth |
>
> Only ripe ones and Rudrakshas which are free from holes are good to wear. During the pranpratishtha of Rudrakshas they are to be bathed first with
>   panchagavyas ( 5 things from cow like her urine, milk etc) and
>   panchamritas ( milk, ghee, sugar etc) and then energised with panchakshara,
>   tryambaka and other Shiva mantras.

And here is the warning i am talking about:

> VinA Mantrena Yo Dhatte RudrAksham Bhuvi Manavah |
>  Sa YAti GhorAn
>   YAvadindrAschaturdasa |
>  Iti Padma PurAne RudrAkshyamAhAtyam..
>
> ............................
>
> One who wears Rudraksha without  mantra lives in dreadful hells for as much
>   amount time as long as the 14 Indras rule.
>
> **Verses are from Padma PurAna.**

And, the 14 mantras given in Padma PurAna are as given below:

> Tatra Kramena MantrAha | OM OM Bhrisam namaha (for one-faced
>   Rudrakshas), OM OM Namaha (for two-faced ones),........ OM Namo Namaha
>   (for 14-faced ones).

As you can see, omitted most mantras as they are to given by the very knowledgeable person who prescribed a Rudraksha for you.

In Skanda PurAna , however, different mantras are given. Here are a few samples of them:

> OM Aim (for one-faced), Om Srim (for two-faced)................... OM
>   TamAm (for 14-faced).

**UPDATE:**

Updating the answer with more relevant information found in the [RudrAksha JabAla Upanishad](http://www.astrojyoti.com/rudrakshajabalaupanishad.htm) (which is linked to the SAma Veda).

> 1. One who wears Rudrakshas, should not use intoxicants, meat, garlic,
>      onions, carrots and all such prohibited things. By wearing Rudrakshas
>      during eclipses, Vishusankranti (the end of Mina and beginning of
>      Mesha Masa), new moon, full moon and other such auspicious days, one
>      is freed of all sins. The base of the Rudraksha bead is Brahma, its
>      navel is Vishnu, its face is Rudra and its hole consists of all gods.
> 2. The four kinds of people, Brahmins, Kshatriyas, Vaisyas and Sudras are
>      born as merely a worthless burden on the earth. The real Brahmin is
>      the white Rudraksha. The red is a Kshatriya. The yellow is a Vaisya.
>      And the black is a Sudra.
> 3. Therefore, a Brahmin should wear white Rudrakshas, a Kshatriya the
>      red, a Vaisya the yellow and a Sudra the black. One should use those
>      Rudraksha-beads which are nice, goodlooking, strong, big, auspicious
>      and thorny. One should avoid those eaten by worms, broken, without
>      thorns, and having sores.

There are also many kinds of them (as already noted), like one-faced, two-faced etc till fourteen faced. One needs to know which one is he wearing.

> Lord Kalagnirudra said: The bead with one face is of the form of the
>   Supreme Truth. A disciplined one (controlling his senses) mingles
>   himself with the one Eternal Truth, after wearing these Rudrakshas.
>   The bead with two faces is of the form of Ardhanarisvara and the
>   devotee wearing it attains the grace of Ardhanarisvara (Siva united
>   with Sakti). The bead with three faces is of the form of the three
>   fires and the devotee wearing it attains the grace of Agni. The bead
>   with four faces is of the form of the four-faced Brahma and the
>   devotee wearing it attains the grace of Brahma. The bead with five
>   faces is of the form of Panchabrahman (the five-faced Siva) and the
>   devotee wearing it attains the grace of Panchabrahman and drives away
>   the sin of homicide. The bead with six faces is of the form of the
>   six-faced Kartikeya or Ganesha and the devotee wearing it attains the
>   grace of wealth and health, clear intellect and wisdom, and
>   purification.

...etc.

And, if you know your type, but do not know which Mantra to chant before wearing it, then you can consult [this page](http://www.rudraksha-ratna.com/p/rudraksha-1-mukhi---21-mukhi).

So, if your RudrAksha is five-faced, for example, then you have to check [this page](http://www.rudraksha-ratna.com/k/5-mukhi-rudraksha) to find the Mantra. And, it gives the following Mantra:

> Om Hreem Namaha

Comment: Thanks I was looking for this answer. By any chance do you know what if someone wore without doing anything prescribed, can these invocations be done on already wore one?

Answer (score 2):

Answers are not correct as they used corrupted translation. Once you are wearing Rudraksh please do not eat onion, garlic, drumstick, moringa, lasoda meat and liquor. That’s it. Remove rudraksh at night while sleeping and don’t wear it while having physical relation.

Answer (score 0):

Rudraksha beads have been revered for centuries for their immense spiritual significance and the positive energies they are believed to possess. These sacred beads, derived from the Rudraksha tree, are cherished by followers of Hinduism and individuals seeking spiritual growth and protection. If you are considering wearing Rudraksha beads, it is important to understand the rules and guidelines associated with their usage. In this comprehensive guide, we will explore the rules for wearing Rudraksha beads and how to harness their spiritual power effectively.

**Selecting the Right Rudraksha Bead**
The first rule when it comes to wearing Rudraksha beads is to choose the right bead that aligns with your intentions and needs. Rudraksha beads come in various mukhi (face) counts, ranging from a single face to twenty-one faces. Each mukhi is associated with different benefits and energies. For example, the [1 Mukhi Rudraksha](https://rashiratanjaipur.net/rudraksha/one-mukhi) is believed to enhance focus and concentration, while the Five Mukhi Rudraksha is associated with good health and overall well-being. It is advisable to consult with a knowledgeable astrologer or Rudraksha expert to determine the most suitable bead for you.

**The Importance of Authenticity**
Authenticity plays a vital role in the effectiveness of Rudraksha beads. It is crucial to ensure that the beads you purchase are genuine and not counterfeit. Genuine Rudraksha beads have a distinct texture, with clear, well-defined grooves called mukhis. They also emit a natural energy when held or worn. To verify the authenticity of the Rudraksha beads, it is recommended to purchase them from reputed sellers or certified suppliers who provide proper certification and authentication.

**Purifying and Energizing the Beads**
Before wearing Rudraksha beads for the first time, it is essential to purify and energize them to cleanse any negative energies they may have absorbed. Start by soaking the beads in clean water overnight. The next morning, rinse them with fresh water while chanting a mantra or your preferred sacred chant. This process helps remove impurities and charges the beads with positive vibrations.

**Wear Rudraksha Beads with Respect**
Rudraksha beads are considered sacred, and it is essential to treat them with reverence and respect. Avoid touching the beads with dirty hands or allowing others to handle them casually. It is advisable to wear Rudraksha beads on a clean body and remove them before entering the bathroom or engaging in activities that may soil or damage the beads.

**Proper Placement and Stringing**
When wearing Rudraksha beads, they are traditionally strung together as a mala (necklace) or bracelet. It is important to ensure that the beads are correctly strung and spaced evenly for comfortable wearing. The string used should be strong and of good quality to prevent breakage. Additionally, it is customary to tie a knot between each bead, which is believed to enhance the energy flow and provide stability.

**Regular Cleansing and Maintenance**
To maintain the purity and effectiveness of your Rudraksha beads, regular cleansing is recommended. This can be done by gently wiping the beads with a clean, soft cloth or by placing them in a bowl of clean water for a few hours. It is important to avoid using chemicals or harsh substances that may damage the beads' surface. With proper care and maintenance, your Rudraksha beads will continue to radiate positive energies for an extended period.

Comment: An excellent, in-depth answer, but one requiring some sources/quotes to back it up. Could you find relevant lines in scriptures or from gurus?