# How to energize Rudraksha?

Tags: shiva, shiva-purana, rudraksha

So recently I got a four-faced Rudraksha which I am planning to wear on MahaShivaratri. But it is said that it should be first energized before wearing. How can I do that by myself?

Comment: The answers in the following post must be helpful:https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16787/what-are-the-rules-for-wearing-rudraksha-bead/18435#18435

Comment: @Rickross never knew there were white rudraksha.. so a brahmin should wear white rudraksha?

Comment: @Rickross also can u plz tell what are panchakshra and trayambk mantra? Are they similar to mahamrityunjay mantra?

Comment: I don't know whether those white Rudrakshas are currently available or not. You have to wear what is currently available.

Comment: Panchakshara-Om namah shivaya, Trayambaka mantra-Mahamrityunjaya mantra.

Comment: @Rickross thanks for clarifying. You should answer this question.

Comment: I will have to reproduce the same thing here and which is not desired.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the rules for wearing Rudraksha bead](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16787/what-are-the-rules-for-wearing-rudraksha-bead)