# Which things should be kept in mind while wearing rudraksh mala?

Tags: scripture, rudraksha

Which things should be avoided while wearing a rudraksh mala according to scriptures?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [What are the rules for wearing Rudraksha bead](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16787/647) ?

Comment: Depends on the number of faces. Although a 5 mukhi rudraksha is the standard all-purpose one which can be worn by anyone. Just keep it clean.